# How to open dialog (Quick Entry view) on Add New Row from child table of Frappe Webform?

Tags: modal-dialog, erpnext, frappe

How to open Dialog box (Quick Entry view) on Add New row of child table of **Webform** like we can open dialog box from **Doctype** as below.

[image]

From **WebForm** it is not allowing me to open dialog box on *Add new Row of child table*.

Can anyone please help me to solve this issue?